# Jquery если чекбокс чекед, то скрыть листбокс фоном

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день!
Jquery если чекбокс чекед, то нужно скрыть листбокс фоном
если пользователь отметил чекбокс, то форма скрывается, если снял, появляется как сделать подскажите, без нажатия всяких кнопок, только чекет анчекет

я сделал так, но это на обработку прогрузки страницы и чому-то не работает все равно

```
    <script>


$(function(){
   $(document).ready(function() {
        if ($("#h_check").is(":checked")) 
        {
        document.getElementById('m_elements').style.display = 'none';   

        }

    </script>
```

Comment: Потому что это какой-то случайный недописанный код?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Суть в том, что ваш код работает только при запуске страницы, а вам нужно, что бы он срабатывал после каждого нажатия на `checkbox`:

```js
$('#h_check').click(function() {
  if($(this).prop('checked')) {
    $('#m_elements').css('display', 'none');
  }else{
    $('#m_elements').css('display', 'block');
  }
});
```

```css
#m_elements {
  display: block;
  height: 100vh;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" id="h_check">
<div id="m_elements"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

У Вас нет обработчика клика (смены состояния) по чекбоксу + путаница со скобками. На дынный момент у Вас при загрузке проверяется чекбокс на состояние `checked`. Если он в этом состоянии, то срабатывает условие.

Можно воспользоваться [.change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/):

```js
$('#h_check').change(function() {
 if (this.checked) {
  $('#m_elements').hide();
 } else {
  $('#m_elements').show();
 }
});
```

```css
.block {
  height: 150px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="h_check"> Чек
<div id="m_elements" class="block"></div>
```

Comment: Ваш вариант более лаконичный

Comment: а чем будет плох toggle?

Comment: @And Ничем не будет плох. Можно и без условия, просто `$('#m_elements').toggle();` в `change()` поместить.